# Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource but it exists in my headers

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to load a url in an iframe but I get error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at origin has been blocked by CORS policy` because `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` even though I specified an allow URL in my headers. Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
const router = express.Router();
const PORT = 5001

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});

app.get('/css', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/css`);
});

app.get('/js', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/js`);
});

app.get('/img', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/img`);
});

app.use('/', router);

//CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://192.168.43.211:5000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.listen(PORT, '192.168.43.211', () => console.log(`Server up on IP 192.168.43.211 PORT 5001`))

//now if I go to http://192.168.43.211:5001 in a browser, index.html will get displayed with CORS issue
//ERROR: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.43.211:5000/' from origin 'http://192.168.43.211:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```html
<!-- CORS issue happens-->
<iframe src="http://192.168.43.211:5000"></iframe>
```

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
const PORT = 5000

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'))
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'))
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/img'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', './views')
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/', require('./routes/pages'))
app.use('/api', require('./controllers/auth'))

//CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '192.168.43.211:5001');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.listen(PORT, '192.168.43.211', () => console.log(`Server up on IP 192.168.43.211 PORT 5000`))
//now if I go to http://192.168.43.211:5000 in a browser, index.ejs will get displayed with no issue
```

Comment: move `app.use(alowCrossDomain)` before your routes ...

Comment: Did you manage it to solve it ?